# Set value of a Variable in .env file from .sh file in Nestjs project

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, .env

I am attempting to set the value of MONGOOSE_URI (in .env file) by configuring its value using a .sh script.

setup.sh
export URL="mongodb+srv.........."

.env
MONGOOSE_URI=$URL

For starting the script, I execute:
source setup.sh && nest start

Upon checking the console, process.env.MONGOOSE_URI returns $URL instead of the actual value.

I tried manually running the .sh file with echo, and it executed correctly. This method has been working in a Next.js project.

Comment: Adding configModule solved it
 ConfigModule.forRoot({
      expandVariables: true,
    }),